How can I use dplyr summarize to create a count of all items and fraction of items in a certain group?
e.g. if I have a list of orders, and want to produce a report listing all customers, their total order volume, and the fraction of their orders that come from a certain product category?
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

ord <- tribble(
  ~name, ~product,
  "Alice", "apple",
  "Alice", "banana",
  "Alice", "cherry",
  "Alice", "apple",
  "Bob", "apple",
  "Bob", "banana",
  "Alice", "apple"
)

i'd be looking for output like:
tribble(
  ~name, ~total_orders, ~apple_fraction,
  "Alice", 5, 0.6,
  "Bob", 2, 0.5
)


If it's the number of apples in a group you are struggling with, you can sum up TRUE values of product == "apple" :
library(dplyr)

ord |> 
  summarise(
    total_orders = n(),
    apple_fraction = sum(product == "apple") / total_orders, 
    .by = name
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   name  total_orders apple_fraction
#>   <chr>        <int>          <dbl>
#> 1 Alice            5            0.6
#> 2 Bob              2            0.5

Created on 2024-10-31 with reprex v2.1.1

this is exactly the kind of one liner I was looking for

one way is a two-step summarize:
ord %>%
  group_by(name, product) %>%
  summarise(orders = n()) %>%
  mutate(frac=orders/sum(orders))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'name'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#> # Groups:   name [2]
#>   name  product orders  frac
#>   <chr> <chr>    <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Alice apple        3   0.6
#> 2 Alice banana       1   0.2
#> 3 Alice cherry       1   0.2
#> 4 Bob   apple        1   0.5
#> 5 Bob   banana       1   0.5

Now we've got counts by name and product, as well as the fraction of that customer's orders that come from this produc type.
Note we don't need to calculate frac here, it's just helpful to check that the next step gives the result we expect.
Using summarize again will strip off one level of grouping--by default it's the last level, i.e. product.
The total order count is trivial: sum(orders).
The fraction coming from a subset can be found by subsetting orders. It turns out you can still subset on product even though product won't be part of the output sum(orders[product=="apple"])/sum(orders).
ord %>%
  group_by(name, product) %>%
  summarise(orders = n()) %>%
  summarise(total_orders = sum(orders),
            frac_apple = sum(orders[product=="apple"])/sum(orders))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'name'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   name  total_orders frac_apple
#>   <chr>        <int>      <dbl>
#> 1 Alice            5        0.6
#> 2 Bob              2        0.5

This approach actually extends nicely to more complex subsetting:
ord %>%
  group_by(name, product) %>%
  summarise(orders = n()) %>%
  summarise(total_orders = sum(orders),
            frac_apple = sum(orders[product=="apple"])/sum(orders),
            frac_red_fruits = sum(orders[product %in% c("apple", "cherry")])/sum(orders))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'name'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   name  total_orders frac_apple frac_red_fruits
#>   <chr>        <int>      <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1 Alice            5        0.6             0.8
#> 2 Bob              2        0.5             0.5

